# Removing a div with certain width with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, media, media-queries

I'm trying to make a pretty different version of a web page for mobile and, for that to happen, **I need certain divs to disappear when the browser window width is bigger then 767px**. I was trying to do it with jQuery with something like this:

```
<script>
if ( $('body').width > 767px ) {
    $('.mobile').remove();
}
</script>
```

but it doesn't work at all.

The divs that I want to disappear in the bigger version have the class `.mobile` .

Comment: It's called CSS media queries, and it does exactly what you're trying to do without javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need JS for that. Have you looked at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) ?

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    .mobile { display: none }    
}
```

if you still want to use jQuery:

```
if ( $('body').width > 767 ) {
    $('.mobile').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm trying media queries and java script for the first time so it got a bit confusing..

Answer (score 1):

Try using media queries, instead.  Look at http://cssmediaqueries.com/

Answer (score 0):

`.width()` will return a pixel value, so you need to check for 767

You could use media queries but browser support should be considered: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 767px) {
  .mobile {display:none;}
}
```

or

```
$('.mobile').toggle(parseInt($('body').width())>767);
```